# Gulp-filter works weird and wrong

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-filter

I have this little piece of code:

```
gulp.src('src/*.*')
    .pipe(filter(['**', '!**/*.{png,jpg,bmp,jpeg,jpeg2,webp,svg}', '!**/*.{css,less}']))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/'));
```

This code should move any files if it is not image or an style. But this filter only filters every file in directory. For example: moves only `src/index.php`, `src/script.js` or `src/page.html`, but `src/assets/script.js` filters

I tried to use one or none asterisks (filters everything). Tried to use only one filter instead of two.

**Why this plugin is so weird? How can i use it correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `gulp-filter` actually.  Your `gulp.src` doesn't include any subfolders.  You have:

`gulp.src('src/*.*')`

should be

`gulp.src('src/**/*.*')`

Comment: Did this fix your issue?  It is good to encourage people to answer your questions if you respond to answers.